# Fruityloops not playing certain notes

Tags: software, fl-studio

I'm new to Fruityloops and sound editing software in general and I wanted to learn more about it. I wanted to recreate a song I like and learn from that process.

Sadly I'm already encountering problems I cant seem to fix myself. There are certain notes that Fruityloops just wont play if there's is another pattern playing at the same time.

In the video provided you can see pattern one and two playing, pattern two is mainly just some short bursts of F#4 and note 1 and 6 of pattern one are also F#4. When both both patterns need to play an f#4 at the same time pattern one stays silent. When I remove pattern two it pattern one DOES play those notes. Does anyone know what's causing this?

Here's a picture of my two patterns:
[image]

Here´s the video where you can see the problem:

Comment: So I never really found out why it didn't play, you'd think the software would understand that even if I use the same instrument that if it's a different pattern it should treat it as two instruments.

But duplicating the instrument fixed the problem for me, if anyone ever finds out why this happened and whether there is a better solution to fix this then I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

It does sound like a conflict in triggers.

Some generators default to monophonic or polyphonic.  Clicking on the generator brings up a window which shows you the sample or instrument you are using.  There are tabs which allow you look through the options.  I haven't use FLStudio in a while to recall which tab it is under but my mind keeps thinking it is in the third tab.  There will be a button for MONO or POLY.

This might not be your problem and I'm thinking it is.  FLStudio and other programs do not accept simultaneous triggers on a single generator.  If in your two rolls you desire the F#4 to be played by both instances at the same time, FL Studio will throw its hands up in the air.  If you delay one channels request for that note, the note that comes last will be the note that plays until the end.  So if your 16th note comes before your quarter note by a 32nd note, the 16th note will be played for a duration of a 32nd while the quarter note will play for both.  Also note that the envelope will also be triggered, so you will notice that the tone might not be played continuously.